# Literal class type member function constraints

Tags: c++

The specification does not seem to put any constraints on the member functions of a literal class type

I have two questions regarding this

**Q1)** Do I have complete liberty over what member functions I can put in?

**Q2)** How do I verify if a class is a literal type?  (Possible method: Define a constexpr object of it and check if it compiles?)

**The only constraints on literal classes I see are:**

• All the data members must have literal type.

• The class must have at least one constexpr constructor.

• If a data member has an in-class initializer, the initializer for a member of built-in type must be a constant expression, or if the member has class type, the initializer must use the member’s own constexpr constructor.

• The class must use default definition for its destructor, which is the member that destroys objects of the class type

(Source: C++ Primer, 5th edition)

Comment: Can you provide some code examples to better explain your question? For example, It's unclear what you mean in your second question by "the class passes as a literal type". Are you wanting to ensure that something happens at compile-time?

Comment: The second question is more of "How can I verify it is indeed a literal class, and not just a normal class". If I do not follow any of the conditions for literal class, the code will still compile, just the class would not be a literal one, right?

Comment: @KyleWillmon https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType

Comment: @KyleWillmon Thanks for suggestion. Question wording edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Yes, you can have any methods you like (excluding constructor/destructor which have constraints). Even including `virtual` methods, if the constructor is `constexpr`.

Q2. As you say, define a `constexpr` variable of that type.  If there is no diagnostic message (and the compiler is conforming) then the type is definitely a [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType).  Note that it is possible for the type to be literal but the code to fail compilation for some other reason.

The definition [in the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#10) seems slightly clearer to me than your quoted definition. For example, there are some cases where a `constexpr` constructor is not required (e.g. a closure or an aggregate).

Comment: Thanks a ton for clearing that up. Can you shed some light on why does that work? How can a compiler know at compile time what a non-constexpr function may return. (Since literals are essentially "evaluate-able" at compile time)

Comment: @User10482 it's not relevant what the function returns, since defining a variable doesn't involve calling the function.  You might not be able to call certain member functions in a constant expression.

Comment: Interesting. So, I cannot use any _ non-constexpr  _ functions defined inside a literal class.

Comment: @User10482 You can use them, just not in a constant expression. Also, even if a function is `constexpr` it still might not be usable in a constant expression (depends on what argument is given)